# Prevent static property being accessed before async function initializes it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I have a function that asynchronously loads a xml file, parses it, and adds certain values to a list.  I'm using async and await for this.  The issue I've run into is that after calling await the program moves on to executing code that accesses that list before the async function has finished adding all items.

My static class with async function:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets;

namespace Drok.Localization
{
    public static class Localization
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The currently available languages.
        /// </summary>
        public static List<string> Available { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
        /// <summary>
        /// The currently selected language.
        /// </summary>
        public static string Current { get; private set; } = null;

        public static async Task Initialize()
        {
            await LoadMetaData();
        }

        private static async Task LoadMetaData()
        {
            AsyncOperationHandle<TextAsset> handle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<TextAsset>("Localization/meta.xml");
            TextAsset metaDataFile = await handle.Task;
            XDocument metaXMLData = XDocument.Parse(metaDataFile.text);
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = metaXMLData.Element("LangMeta").Elements();
            foreach (XElement e in elements)
            {
                string lang = e.Attribute("lang").Value;
                int id = Int32.Parse(e.Attribute("id").Value);
                Debug.LogFormat("Language {0} is availible with id {1}.", lang, id);
                Available.Add(lang);
            }
        }

        public static void LoadLanguage(string lang)
        {
            Current = lang;
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static string GetString(string key)
        {
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

The class that initializes it and accesses the list:

```
using Drok.Localization;

using UnityEngine;

namespace Spellbound.Menu
{
    public class LanguageMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private async void Awake()
        {
            await Localization.Initialize();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log(Localization.Available.Count);
        }

        private void Update()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to prevent access to that list until after all items have been added.  The code I posted just collects info on what languages are available so that only the one language being used can be loaded later.

Comment: Add some logic to the `get` accessor that ensures initialization is complete before returning the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Task<T>` represents some value (of type `T`) that will be determined in the future. If you make your property this type, then it will force all callers to `await` for it to be loaded:

```
public static class Localization
{
  public static Task<List<string>> Available { get; private set; }

  static Localization() => Available = LoadMetaDataAsync();

  private static async Task<List<string>> LoadMetaDataAsync()
  {
    var results = new List<string>();
    ...
      results.Add(lang);
    return results;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
private async Task StartAsync()
{
  var languages = await Localization.Available;
  Debug.Log(languages.Available.Count);
}
```

Comment: Usage would be `Debug.Log(languages.Count);`, right?

Comment: This seems like the most viable option for my situation.  I was just hoping that there was a way to avoid having to repeat 'await' every time I need to access it.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility might be to add some logic to wait for the metadata to be loaded when returning the list from the `get` accessor.

One way to do this is to have a `bool` field that is set to `true` when the list is ready, and then we either return a private backing `List<string>` or `null`, depending on the value of our `bool` field:

```
public static class Localization
{
    private static bool metadataLoaded = false;
    private static List<string> available = new List<string>();

    // The 'Available' property returns null until the private list is ready
    public static List<string> Available => metadataLoaded ? available : null;

    private static async Task LoadMetaData()
    {
        // Add items to private 'available' list here

        // When the list is ready, set our field to 'true'
        metadataLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems closer to something that may fit my needs but the main issue i'm seeing is that I get null instead of a correct value.  Would there possibly be a way to just tell it to wait until it's done rather than just returning null?

Comment: `public static List<string> Available {get{while(!metadataLoaded); return available;}}` This will wait until the metadata is loaded, but it could cause hanging in the client while it's waiting. For example, if they try to access the list before calling `Initialize`, they will wait forever.

Comment: Hmmm that does cause hanging even if I call LoadMetaData before accessing Available whether I do it manually or in a static constructor.

Comment: @StephenCleary has a very nice answer that allows the client to `await` the collection, which may be your best bet.

Comment: That seems like it will be my best option at least for now.  I was trying to avoid repeated code ie await.

Answer (score 2):

The `Awake` method is async void, so there is no way for the caller to guarantee that it finishes before moving on to something else.

However, you could preserve the task and await it in the `Start` method to ensure that it is completed. Awaiting it twice does not harm anything.

```
public class LanguageMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Task _task;

    private async void Awake()
    {
        _task = Localization.Initialize();
        await _task;
    }

    private async void Start()
    {
        await _task;
        Debug.Log(Localization.Available.Count);
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: See I thought about doing something like this but the list and other things that this will initialize later are going to be accessed in so many different places it seems unreasonable to keep checking if it has completed, no?

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to treat the async call when loading as synchronous? Or an alternate way to only load the files into memory when needed thats not async.  I expanded on my use case in the original post if it helps at all.

Comment: Sure, remove `async` from all those methods and let them run synchronously. Why did you add `async` to begin with?

Comment: If memory serves I was getting a nullpointer exception if I didn't await the load.
Edit:  Yeah just checked and if i change all the methods to not be async and say _TextAsset metaDataFile = handle.Result;_ i get a null pointer when I try to parse it.  I'd assume this is because the load method is still async since I can't change that.

Comment: Have you tried [`LoadAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAsset.html) instead of `LoadAssetAsync`?

Comment: That is both deprecated and still returns an AsyncOperationHandler.  Seems like it would synchronous but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Rufus' comment:

Declare a `bool` property that's initialized to `false`. And in your list's getter, return the list only if the said `bool` property is `true`, and return maybe `null` (this depends on your requirements) if `false`.

```
public static bool IsAvailable { get; set; } = false;

private static List<string> _available;
public static List<string> Available
{
    get
    {
        if (IsAvailable)
            return _available;
        else
            return null;
    }
    set { _available = value; }
}
```

Finally, in your `async` function, when the work is done set the above property to true.

Answer (score 0):

Latest when there is an `Update` method involved that should also wait with its execution using `async` and `await` might not be enough anyway.

Usually there is always one big alternative to using `async` for the Unity messages: an event system like e.g.

```
public static class Localization
{
    public static event Action OnLocalizationReady;

    public static async void Initialize()
    {
        await LoadMetaData();

        OnLocalizationReady?.Invoke();
    }

    ...
}
```

And wait for that event in any class using it like e.g.

```
public class LanguageMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool locaIsReady;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Localization.OnLocalizationReady -= OnLocalizationReady;
        Localization.OnLocalizationReady += OnLocalizationReady;

        Localization.Initialize();
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        Localization.OnLocalizationReady -= OnLocalizationReady;
    }

    // This now replaces whatever you wanted to do in Start originally
    private void OnLocalizationReady ()
    {
        locaIsReady = true;

        Debug.Log(Localization.Available.Count);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Block execution until locaIsReady
        if(!locaIsReady) return;

        ...
    }
}
```

Or for minimal better performance you could also set `enabled = false` in `Awake` and set it to true in `OnLocalizationReady` then you could get rid of the `locaIsReady` flag.

---

No `async` and `await` needed.

---

If you would move the `Localization.Initialize();` instead to `Start` you would give other classes the chance to also add some callbacks before to `Localization.OnLocalizationReady` in `Awake` ;)

---

And you can extend this in multiple ways! You could e.g. together with firering the event directly also pass in the reference to `Availables` so listeners can directly use it like e.g.

```
public static class Localization
{
    public static event Action<List<string>> OnLocalizationReady;

    ...
}
```

and then in `LanguageMenu` change the signiture of `OnLocalizationReady` to

```
public class LanguageMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    // This now replaces whatever you wanted to do in Start originally
    private void OnLocalizationReady(List<string> available)
    {
        locaIsReady = true;

        Debug.Log(available.Count);
    }
}
```

---

If anyway `LanguageMenu` will be the only listener then you could even pass the callback directly as parameter to `Initialize` like

```
public static class Localization
{
    public static async void Initialize(Action<List<string>> onSuccess)
    {
        await LoadMetaData();

        onSuccess?.Invoke();
    }

    ...
}
```

and then use it like

```
private void Awake()
{
    Localization.Initialize(OnLocalizationReady);
}

private void OnLocalizationReady(List<string>> available)
{
    locaIsReady = true;

    Debug.Log(available.Count);
}
```

or as lambda expression

```
private void Awake()
{
    Localization.Initialize(available => 
    {
        locaIsReady = true;

        Debug.Log(available .Count);
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

As to your question about later Initialization: Yes there is a simple fix as well

```
public static class Localization
{
    public static event Action OnLocalizationReady;

    public static bool isInitialized;

    public static async void Initialize()
    {
        await LoadMetaData();

        isInitialized = true;
        OnLocalizationReady?.Invoke();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in other classes you can do it conditional either use callbacks or Initialize right away:

```
private void Awake()
{
    if(Localization.isInitialized)
    {
        OnLocaInitialized();
    }
    else
    {
        Localization.OnInitialized -= OnLocaInitialized;
        Localization.OnInitialized += OnLocaInitialized;
    }
}

private void OnDestroy ()
{
    Localization.OnInitialized -= OnLocaInitialized;
}

private void OnLocaInitialized()
{
    var available = Localization.Available;

    ...
}

private void Update()
{
    if(!Localization.isInitialized) return;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but at least for my case I can't guarantee that all objects that need to access that can listen to the event before it is invoked.  Anyway around that with this method?

Comment: Actually yes .. just used it today ;) Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was only really breaking test harnesses, that works as below. Below that is my solution to this similar/maybe identical problem.

The website uses data that is very rarely updated, but very frequently accessed. The data sits in structured data in the database. A projection of it is loaded once at app startup for fast in-memory access.

Most pages on the site don't care if this data is loaded yet or not, and the ones that do are unlikely to be accessed at site startup because they're several steps into a multi-page flow. But once a user gets that far this data is accessed over and over and again, it won't change until several deployments later, when the entire app pool will reset and this cache will be renewed.

So, the data is accessed by a synchronous static getter, like:

```
DataCache.O
```

And this is set like:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        TaskHelper.RunBg(DataCache.Init);
```

Where TaskHelper.RunBg just runs an async method on a background thread (we don't want to block synchronous Application_Start() with an async method).

```
public class DataCache
{
    public static DataCache O { get; protected set; }

    public static async Task Init()
    {
        using(var db = DbFactory.O.CheapReads())
        {
            await Load(db);
```

The problem was that test harness code will load up and hit the important stuff a lot faster than normal, production code, so it's common the test would just error out because it asked for this DataCache before this app init could prepare it. The solution is I used is to offer the Task up to the test harness code:

```
public class DataCache
{
    public static DataCache O { get; protected set; }

    public static Task<DataCache> LoadingTask { get; protected set; }

    public static async Task Init()
    {
        using(var db = DbFactory.O.CheapReads())
        {
            await Load(db);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<DataCache> Load(Db db)
    {
        LoadingTask = load(db);
        return await LoadingTask;
    }

    protected static async<DataCache> load(Db db)
    {
        ... DataCache loading code goes here
```

And then in the code the Test Harness may use to access this, replace:

```
var dataCache = DataCache.O;
```

with:

```
var dataCache = await DataCache.LoadingTask;
```

Depending on the Test Harness call, this may mean multiple subscribing threads are spawned, all awaiting - basically all subscribing to the completion event - of this one loading task. The TPL handles the multiple subscriber problem for you with no extra work.

Although this means most of the time the await returns synchronously, I haven't tested this but it seems like the TPL is happy to optimize for async methods that return sync most of the time, so the performance impact should be negligible (and it's mostly for test code anyway). And when it does run async, it prevents accessing the static data when it isn't quite ready.

In fairness, it may be smarter to never offer this data synchronously, and always offer it just the one way - through that LoadingTask.

There are cases where this still isn't enough - my test code gets to even asking for the LoadingTask before the MvcApp Init can set it, let alone finish it. This can be solved with [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-7.0):

```
public class DataCache
{
    protected static TaskCompletionSource<DataCache> loadingTcs = new ...

    public static Task<DataCache> LoadingTask
    {
        get => loadingTcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task<DataCache> Load(Db db)
    {
        ... run the long-running Db query
        O = (the loaded data)
        loadingTcs.SetResult(O);
        return O;
    }
```

Now you've got a class that immediately provides a Task, even if the Init code hasn't gotten around to starting it yet, but, won't mark it completed until after the init code has started it, and it's had its time to run.